# Having trouble getting a double header using HTML

Tags: html, django, header

I'm having trouble getting a double header set up.
Both headers seem to be one on top of the other, especially when I inspect the header. This is on Django if that changes anything

```
<body> <section><header class="site-header">
         ...
      </header></section>
      <section><header class="site-header">
         ... 
      </header></section>

</body>
```

from main.css

```
.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in your "site-header" class? Sections are block elements and should not overlap. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

Unrelated to your direct question - why do you need to wrap the headers in sections?

Comment: I just added the site-header info from my CSS file. Honestly, I tried wrapping it in sections to get it to differentiate because I read somewhere that you need to differentiate your headers if you're going to have two.

Comment: There must be some other CSS that is causing the headers to overlap. E.g. an absolute position. If you can't see it in a file, you could use the browser inspector to investigate